# Change one node type in Tensorflow graph

Tags: tensorflow

So I have a tensorflow graph saved in a `.pb` file, it works well on my machine, but when I run it on tensorflow v 1.3 it loads fine though it crashes with the following error

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'Reshape' with these attrs.  Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels:
  device='CPU'; Tshape in [DT_INT32]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_COMPLEX128]; Tshape in [DT_INT32]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_COMPLEX64]; Tshape in [DT_INT32]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_INT8]; Tshape in [DT_INT32]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_UINT8]; Tshape in [DT_INT32]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_INT16]; Tshape in [DT_INT32]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_UINT16]; Tshape in [DT_INT32]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_INT64]; Tshape in [DT_INT32]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_DOUBLE]; Tshape in [DT_INT32]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]; Tshape in [DT_INT32]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_HALF]; Tshape in [DT_INT32]

           [[Node: Reshape_165 = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT64](transpose_145, add_31)]]
```

After investigating I found out that the `Reshape_165` operation is of shape `DT_INT64` and v1.3 doesn't support`DT_INT64` for `Reshape` as the message reads, so I was wondering if there's a way to change the `Reshape_165` operation dtype to `DT_INT32` mind you the whole graph gets executed but for this operation which is the one just before the outputs `concat_52` and `concat_53`

```
add_31
Reshape_165
concat_52/axis
concat_52
concat_53/axis
concat_53
```

Comment: One hack is to export Graph as Json, edit it and load it back as protobuf. Does that work in this situation ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41575442/tensorflow-export-compute-graph-to-xml-json-etc

Comment: Let me give it a try @ShamitVerma

Comment: @ShamitVerma but about the weights?

Comment: Weights should be included in Json version.

Comment: I tried it out, but unfortunately it doesn’t work and throws `can’t convert int64 to int32`